# Inconsistent conversion of JavaScript Date objects by arithmetic operators

Tags: javascript

What Javascript language rule leads to the following conversion weirdness?

```
new Date() - 2 => number
new Date() * 2 => number
new Date() / 2 => number
```

but

```
new Date() + 2 => string
```

I had thought that the + operator would use the `valueOf()` method of the `Date` object to convert it to a number. Like in the following example:

```
{valueOf: function() {return 1;}} + 2 => number
```

What is different in the case of a `Date`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying the Javascript spec, there is indeed a special case for Date objects in the context of the addition operator:

http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1

Conversion of a Date object is handled differently than for other objects:

> No hint is provided in the calls to ToPrimitive in steps 5 and 6. All
>   native ECMAScript objects except Date objects handle the absence of a
>   hint as if the hint Number were given; Date objects handle the absence
>   of a hint as if the hint String were given.

I think I understand the motivation, but as a language rule, this feels quite ugly.

Comment: I feel that in order to be utterly beautiful you need something ugly with it. It's easier to sympathize that way and the beauty is complete.

Answer (score 3):

when you try to do

```
new Date() + 2
```

you're doing a string concatenation (so `new Date()` is returning a string representation of the `Date` object equivalent to `(new Date()).toString()`),

In the in other cases you're using an arithmetic operator (and in this case `new Date()` returns the milliseconds from "Epoch")

To have a *"consistent"* behaviour make a type coercion just using `+(new Date())` so that

```
+(new Date()) - 2 => number
+(new Date()) * 2 => number
+(new Date()) / 2 => number
+(new Date()) + 2 => number
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how your example is related: new Date is internally using a toString() method when used in conjunction with `+` and `string + number ==> string`

Comment: How is the example not related? Both `new Date()` and `{valueOf: function() {return 1;}}` are objects with a `valueOf` function. In one case the + operator calls `valueOf` in the other it calls `toString`. That's what I would call inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

It's not inconsistent: Just try `d = new Date(); console.log(d);` the `toString` method, that is implicitly invoked in the above code returns a string by default. Since JS is loosely typed, and `+` is an overloaded operator (concatenates strings, and does arithmetic), both the date object and the int (2) are coerced:

I guess the logic behind this is something like: if neither operand is directly compatible, both are coerced to a third type: sort of *"Meeting each other half-way"*. Dates are converted to strings by default, and a number can do that, too, so JS assumes that is what you want (it being the most *logic* interpretation). 
The other examples use different operands, that leave no room for interpretation, hence the date-object's numeric value is used

It's an easy fix, though:

```
+(new Date()) + 2;//+ coerces new Date() to int
```

Here's [some more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007379/what-makes-new-date-1000-a-valid-javascript/12007624)

Comment: @IngoKegel: My mistake: it's not the valueOf method, but the `toString` method that gets called. I assumed it would have been the valueOf method, too, but once again I am reminded that you can't assume native objects to behave like regular objects

Comment: OK, so you think it's a special exception for Date objects. Is that documented anywhere?

Comment: @IngoKegel: Yes, indeed the Date object is the exception that proves the rule. I see you've found the section in the ECMA std that deals with this. I really don't think you're not alone in saying this is an ugly (some would even say idiotic) construct. Sadly, it's been around since the stone-age, and it's unlikely to change any time soon